# Copying from one pandas dataframe to another based on values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to work with 2 different dataframes (df1 and df2) which hold information about the same people. I would like to take information from one and move it to the other. Merging the dataframes doesn't work because there are some people missing from DF2.

Basically I want to use the shared columns to look up info from one DF and move it to the other.

**DF1**

|  | Name | ID | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | 001 | 89 |
| 1 | Jane | 002 | 56 |
| 2 | Joan | 003 | 91 |
| 3 | David | 004 | 45 |

**DF2**

|  | Name | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jane | Group 1 |
| 1 | David | Group 1 |
| 2 | Joan | Group 2 |
| 3 | John | Group 2 |

I have tried things like,

```
for i in df1['Name'].values:
    for j in df2['Name'].values:
        if i == j:
            df1['Group'] = df2['Group'].values
```

I'm hoping to end up with something like

**DF1**

|  | Name | ID | Grade | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | 001 | 89 | Group 2 |
| 1 | Jane | 002 | 56 | Group 1 |
| 2 | Joan | 003 | 91 | Group 2 |
| 3 | David | 004 | 45 | Group 1 |

A direct answer would be great but if anyone can recommend resources that cover working with multiple dataframes that would be awesome as well.

Comment: Merge with `how=left` ?   Like `df1.merge(df2, how=left, ...)`

Comment: If ID is unique for one person, merge on ID ?

Comment: so something like 
``` df1 = df1.merge(df2, how =left)```

Comment: Yes, e.g.  `df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='ID')`

Comment: This produces nans for some reason.

Comment: Or merge on name if there is no ID on df2

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that df2 has no ID.  In that case you can merge on name

Comment: Let me put it as an answer to give more details

Comment: Question closed.  Can't post answer.  You can use `df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Name')`.   Using left join will use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; preserve key order.